# KeyUp not working Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have made a number of tests and I'm using selenium to run them. For a certain test I need to use a number of shortcuts. However for some reason my `keyUp` doesn't work which then knocks off my other shortcuts. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

Has anyone got any ideas why?

My code is as follows

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys(Keys.Tab).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Build().Perform();
Thread.Sleep(4000);
excelSession.FindElementByName("elementName").Click();
action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("CFNC").KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Build().Perform();
Thread.Sleep(4000);
Thread.Sleep(4000);
TearDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code wise it seems fine, does the form you are sending keys to have a 4 character limit? It could be that typing that fourth character makes the current form non-active and switches it another object.

For this scenario you could also replace that line with

WebElement typeInto = excelSession.FindElementByName("elementName");
typeInto.sendKeys("CFNC" + Keys.ALT);

Or something like that.

Comment: Is there a way I can release all keys after a test is done?

Comment: Did you mix up the shift and control keys here? action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys(Keys.Tab).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Build().Perform();